# Karate framework: how to get timestamp and append to a variable

Tags: java, datetime-format, karate, localdatetime

I wish to get the system timestamp and append it to filename

```
Scenario: fielanem timestamp
* def filename = 'samplefilename.txt'
* def timestamp = java.type("java.time.localdatetime").now()
* print timestamp
```

I need to get the current timestamp and append it to filename.
output : samplefilenameYYYYMMDDHHMMSS.txt

Answer (score 3):

for timestamp you can use

```
* def getDate =
  """
  function() {
    var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
    var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMddHHmmss');
    var date = new java.util.Date();
    return sdf.format(date);
  } 
  """

* def temp = getDate()
* print temp
* def filename = 'samplefilename.txt'
* def finalfilename = filename.split('.')[0]+temp+'.txt'
* print finalfilename
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 3):

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Using the modern date-time and formatting API, you can do it as follows:

```
* def getDate =
  """
  function() {
    var DateTimeFormatter = Java.type('java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter');
    var dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('uuuuMMddHHmmss');
    var ldt = java.time.LocalDateTime.now();
    return ldt.format(dtf);
  } 
  """

* def temp = getDate()
* print temp
* def filename = 'samplefilename.txt'
* def finalfilename = filename.split('.')[0]+temp+'.txt'
* print finalfilename
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Note that `LocalDateTime.now()` returns date-time in your JVM's timezone i.e. it gives a value equal to `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. If you want to get the local date-time with a particular timezone-offset e.g. with timezone-offset of `+00:00` hours i.e. `ZoneOffset.UTC`, you need to use [`LocalDateTime now(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) e.g. `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)`.